# Why is car1.name inaccessible in this code?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


class car 
{
private:
    string name;
    int horsepower;
    string price;
public:
    void setname(string aname)
    {
        name = aname;
    }
    string getname()
    {
        return name;
    }

     car(string aname, int ahorsepower, string aprice)
    {
         name=aname;
         horsepower=ahorsepower;
         price=aprice;
    }
};

int main()
{
    car car1= car("ferrari", 500, "300k");
    cout << car1.name;
    return 0;
}
```

The getter should extract the information as far as i know.I have no idea what to do as I have just started OOP today. What could be the issue?

Comment: The getter `getname` might be public, but the attribute `name` is not. You need to invoke your getter method instead.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it is working now with car1.getname(). :))

Comment: because it's private?